# What i need to do on resize event of full calendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

```
        eventResize: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta) {
         },
```

How i need to update calendar event on resize or move event?

Comment: [Refresh](http://fullcalendar.io/docs1/removed/refresh/) or [RefreshEvents](http://fullcalendar.io/docs1/event_data/refetchEvents/)? Second Google result. Not used fullcalendar personally.

Answer (score 0):

To resize ur event, just add :

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
 header: { left: 'prev,next today', center: 'title', right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'},
.
.
.
eventAfterRender: function(event, element, view) {
   $(element).css('width','70px');
   $(element).css('height','10px');
},
.
.
.
});
```

I tested it and it's working for me. I hope I help you.
Regards,